# Error: htmlParseStartTag: misplaced <head> tag, error parsing attribute name, Unexpected end tag : form

Tags: html, r, parsing

I need to get data from the site:http://www.srh.noaa.gov/data/obhistory/KSPA.html

My code runs good in R, but before I scheduled a crontab in server, I run the data in Putty, repeated error generated: "htmlParseStartTag: misplaced  tag, error parsing attribute name, Unexpected end tag : form"

Some of the related posts are php, I'm not familiar with that language, anybody knows how to fix the problem in R language? Thanks.

Here is my R code:

```
LocIDs <- c("KSPA","KALX","K3A1","KTOI")
library(XML)   

urls <- paste("http://www.srh.noaa.gov/data/obhistory/",LocIDs,".html", sep="")

data <- lapply(urls, function(x) {
dat <- tryCatch(readHTMLTable(x,header=F,which=4,stringsAsFactors=F),error=function(e) NULL)
 dat$LocID = substr(x, 40, 43)           # Add a column of LocID(4 characters)
 dat <- dat[-c(1:3),c(1,2,7,8,11,14,17)]
 dat <- head(dat, -3)                    # Delete first & last 3 column of table names
 return(dat)                                                                   
})                                                                              

#Structure list to data.frame
library(plyr)
data3 <- do.call(rbind.fill, data)
```

Comment: The messages are caused by malformed HTML coming from the NOAA server. Unless you can persuade them to fix their pages, you'll need to work around it yourself, which means either ignoring the errors and disabling the messages (if you can get the data you want), or finding another way to parse the HTML that copes with the problem.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestions, looks like I need to find another way to parse the HTML since I was not able to get the data in Putty, any suggestions on that?

Comment: Can't help with `R` - not my thing. The NOAA site has a number of XML feeds available which might have the information you want, and hopefully will be more reliable. I only found current observations in XML, so you might have to query them more often. It's possible the three-day content is available in XML, but I didn't find it. The other approach is to read the HTML, and search the raw code for the data you want. Messy, but possibly more reliable than the parser you're using.

Comment: I tried XML before, and query them every hour, but had many missing data, that's why I tried the HTML, thought it finally worked in R, who knows pop the error when to schedule the crontab...anyway, Thank YOU for ur help, I'll keep trying, and hopefully anybody good with R have any suggestions